# Issues with activating models in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm following this tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/  to learn Django. Here is the code for my model.py file.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here

class Question(models.Model):
   question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

When I run the following command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations polls
```

I see that only the model question is being created and not the model choice.  When I try to the edit the model.py file and rerun the 'makemigration polls' command, I get the following error:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'pub_date' to question without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with the code here. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Did you run `manage.py migrate` after you ran the `makemigrations polls`?

Comment: I ran  python manage.py sqlmigrate polls 0001 as per the tutorial and I saw the following output. There is no mention of the model choice being created.                         
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Question
--
CREATE TABLE "polls_question" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "question_text" varchar(200) NOT NULL);

COMMIT;

Comment: And I can see that pub_Date is not taken care of either.

Comment: DId you first create the Model as `class Question(models.Model):
   question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)`, ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and then added `pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')` ?

Comment: Hi Nagaraj, No I ran makemigrations only after creating the model : class Question(models.Model):
   question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
 all at once

Comment: looks like this has something to do with pub_date not having a default value specified. What do you think?

Comment: If `pub_date` was missing when you first ran the makemigrations command, then it will not be there in the initial migration.

Comment: As I said, this error will only come, if you already had the table created first and then added `pub_date` to the model and ran the makemigrations. I just verified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to provide a default value to the DateTimeField. So,
change following line of your code:

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

**to this**

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got out of sync. Delete your database file, and the Python files under polls/migrations, and run makemigrations again.

This was caused by you not having the pub_date field when you initially migrated. There are ways of fixing this, but for the purposes of the tutorial, you should just start again.